# Fill DataFrame row values based on another dataframe row's values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame1:

```
Device  MedDescription  Quantity

RWCLD   Acetaminophen (TYLENOL) 325 mg Tab  54
RWCLD   Ampicillin Inj (AMPICILLIN) 2 g Each    13
RWCLD   Betamethasone Inj *5mL* (CELESTONE SOLUSPAN) 30 mg (5 mL) Each  2
RWCLD   Calcium Carbonate Chew (500mg) (TUMS) 200 mg Tab    17
RWCLD   Carboprost Inj *1mL* (HEMABATE) 250 mcg (1 mL) Each 5
RWCLD   Chlorhexidine Gluc Liq *UD* (PERIDEX/PERIOGARD) 0.12 % (15 mL) Each 5
```

Data Frame2:

```
Device  DrwSubDrwPkt    MedDescription  BrandName   MedID   PISAlternateID  CurrentQuantity Min Max StandardStock   ActiveOrders    DaysUnused

RWC-LD  RWC-LD_MAIN Drw 1-Pkt 12    Mag/AlOH/Smc 200-200-20/5 *UD* (MYLANTA/MAALOX) (30 mL) Each    MYLANTA/MAALOX  A03518  27593   7   4   10  N   Y   3
RWC-LD  RWC-LD_MAIN Drw 1-Pkt 20    ceFAZolin in Dextrose(ISO-OS) (ANCEF/KEFZOL) 1 g (50 mL) Each   ANCEF/KEFZOL    A00984  17124   6   5   8   N   N   2
RWC-LD  RWC-LD_MAIN Drw 1-Pkt 22    Clindamycin Phosphate/D5W (CLEOCIN) 900 mg (50 mL) IV Premix    CLEOCIN A02419  19050   7   6   8   N   N   2
```

What I want to do is append DataFrame2 values to Data Frame 1 ONLY if the 'MedDescription' matches. When it find the match, I would like to add only certain columns from dataFrame2[Min,Max,Days Unused] which are all integers

I had an iterative solution where I access the dataframe 1 object 1 row at a time and then check for a match with dataframe 2, once found I append the column numbers from there to the original dataFrame.

Is there a better way? It is making my computer slow to a crawl as I have thousands upon thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to merge the target columns ('MedDescription', 'Min', 'Max', 'Days Unused') to df1 based on a matching 'MedDescription'.

I believe the best way to do this is as follows:

```
target_cols = ['MedDescription', 'Min', 'Max', 'Days Unused']
df1.merge(df2[target_cols], on='MedDescription', how='left')
```

how='left' ensures that all the data in `df1` is returned, and only the target columns in df2 are appended if MedDescription matches.

Note:  It is easier for others if you copy the results of df1/df2.to_dict(). The data above is difficult to parse.

Comment: i tried this, it worked, but it changed the index from the UNIT itself to numbers

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an opportunity to use Pandas' [built-in functions for joining datasets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) - you should be able to join on `MedDescription` with a the desired columns from DataFrame2. The `join` function in Pandas is very efficient, and should far outperform your method of looping through.

Pandas has [documentation on merging datasets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) that includes some good examples, and you can find ample literature on the concepts of joins in SQL tutorials.

Comment: yeah I looked at that doc, but that had values being merged based on index, unfortunately for me, my dataframe has a constant index(the device name), is it possible to have 2 indexes?

Comment: got it to work `pd.merge(ld,ldAc,on='MedDescription',how='outer')`

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(ld,ldAc,on='MedDescription',how='outer')
```

This is the way I used to join the 2 DataFrames, it seems to work, although it deleted one of the Indexes that contained the devices.