# Fill pandas dataframe rows from values in another dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes as given below:

df1

```
Name   City        Postal_Code     State
James  Phoenix        85003         AZ
John   Scottsdale     85259         AZ
Jeff   Phoenix        85003         AZ
Jane   Scottsdale     85259         AZ
```

df2

```
Postal_Code       Income       Category
  85003            41038         Two
  85259            104631        Four
```

I would like to insert two columns, `Income` and `Category`, to `df1` by capturing the values for `Income` and `Category` from `df2` corresponding to the `postal_code` for each row in `df1`.

The closest question that I could find in SO was this - [Fill DataFrame row values based on another dataframe row's values pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019437/fill-dataframe-row-values-based-on-another-dataframe-rows-values-pandas). But, the pd.merge solution does not solve the problem for me. Specifically, I used

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on='postal_code',how='outer')
```

All I got was `nan` values in the two new columns. Not sure whether this is because the no of rows for `df1` and `df2` are different. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have the wrong how, use `'inner'` instead. This matches where keys exist in both dataframes

```
df1.Postal_Code = df1.Postal_Code.astype(int)
df2.Postal_Code = df2.Postal_Code.astype(int)


df1.merge(df2,on='Postal_Code',how='inner')


    Name        City  Postal_Code State  Income Category
0  James     Phoenix        85003    AZ   41038      Two
1   Jeff     Phoenix        85003    AZ   41038      Two
2   John  Scottsdale        85259    AZ  104631     Four
3   Jane  Scottsdale        85259    AZ  104631     Four
```

Comment: No luck with this either. The output is an empty dataframe.

Comment: Updated, make sure they are the same type